# Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am using android studio artic fox ,trying to install intel x86 Emulator accelerator (Haxm installer)
I tried installing the exe files from [github](https://github.com/intel/haxm) But still it didn't worked. The error log is below

```
Packages to install: 
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)

Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_6_5.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\prannav\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" complete.
Failed to update status to COMPLETE
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
```

Comment: If you manually execute `extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\haxm-7.6.5-setup.exe` a log file will be created in the same directory. Manually execute it and check the log for error messages.

Comment: Can you add the step you took for installation ? Like which commands did you ran ?